# Как изменить запрос в python?

Tags: python, requests, web-scraping

Сайт отправляет запрос, где во вкладке **Запрос** указывает параметр с определенным значением, например

```
number: 0
```

[image]

В ответ на сайт прилетает Json файл, зависящий от вышеуказанного значения. (0 - первая страница, 1 - вторая и т.д.), при этом в URL нет никаких изменяемых параметров. Как вручную изменить значение параметра **number**, что бы получить необходимую страницу?

Comment: про какую вкладу речь не понял. а запрос идет GET или POST, не смотрели в `cntr+shift+I`  во кладке `Network` ? Если GET то просто найти соответствующий параметр в урле. Если POST затрудняюсь ответить.

Comment: POST запрос, в URL никаких изменяемых параметров нет

Comment: POST запрос советуют сделать AJAX-вызовом в консоли Chrome, к примеру. Javascript используя.

Comment: ссылку на сайт скинте, а то слишком долго гадать на кофейной гуще

Comment: https://lesegais.ru/open-area/deal

Comment: Увы, не могу открыть сайт в браузере.

Comment: @El1syum Можно использовать POSTMAN туда cURL и менять все параметры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не большая инструкция в виде гифки (лень расписовать) для Firefox[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: спасибо большое!