# Парсинг сайта и POST запросы

Tags: python, post, requests

Есть страница, например такая: https://stl-nn.com/santehnika/dushevye-ogragdeniya/poddon-elipso-pro-90-flat-belyy-xa237711010/

На ней после загрузки сразу подгружаются конкретные элементы, а именно интересуют данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просмотрев запросы к странице я нашел что все 8 блоков подгружаются одинаковыми способами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извиняюсь за необразованность в данном вопросе. И вот в Response данного запроса как раз и содержится то что мне нужно
Как же я могу получить это все?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1420241/470333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный запрос мою проблему. Он возращал блоки кода, которые подгружались и нужны были мне:

```
datas = {
    'dispatch': 'ab__ia_joins.pc_get_join_products',
    'b': '244',
    'j': '92',
    'p': '89569',
    'is_ajax': '1'
}
res = requests.post('https://stl-nn.com/index.php?dispatch=ab__ia_joins.pc_get_join_products', headers=headers, data=datas)
some_html = res.json()['products_scroller']
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).