# Как спарсить каталог Леруа мерлен на Python?

Tags: python, selenium, requests, web-scraping

При парсинге сайта через requests подгружается JavaScript:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />

<script src="/__qrator/qauth_utm_v2.js"></script>
```

Немного погуглив в интернете решил парсить через selenium, но при парсинге через него сайт блокирует доступ, отображая данное сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие есть идеи решения проблемы? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Через Selenium

```
import time
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://leroymerlin.ru/')
time.sleep(10)
```

предварительно устанавливаем Selenium

[Через requests](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445320/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-leroy-merlin)